# How to create a second y-axis in plot in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

There are two plots with same x-axis. The y-axis value for one plot is much smaller than the other. So plot#1 appears squashed compared to the other. I do not want to use a log scaling or any other type of scaling. How to create a secondary axis `Show` plot such that the scales for both Plot1 and Plot2 are displayed on either side?

```
Plot1 = Plot[{Sin[t]}, {t, -10, 10}] 
Plot2 = Plot[{500*Cos[t]}, {t, -10, 10}] 
Show[Plot1, Plot2]
```

Comment: See [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesPlot"][{Sin[t], 500*Cos[t]}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

```
data = Transpose@Table[{{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 500*Cos[t]}}, {t, -10, 10, 1/10}];

ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesListPlot"][data, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Or with [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) you can use [`MultiaxisArrangement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html)

```
ListLinePlot[data,
 MultiaxisArrangement -> All]
```

[image]